# Select no banco utilizando "like"

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer um select no banco mysql, mas gostaria de usar o `like`, que deveria receber o valor de uma variável do java. Como posso fazer essa interação?

```
public void returInfoClient(userClient) {

    Connection mConn = (new ConnectionFactory()).getConnection();

    String sql = "SELECT nameClient, userClient, descriptionClient, passwordClient, birtDate 
                  FROM Client 
                  WHERE userClient LIKE 'userClient%';" //quero que o userClient venha do parametro da função
                  + "values(?);";

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = mConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, userClient); //quero usar o userClient do parametro da função para o like do select
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
        System.out.println("retornando informações author");
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua query está errada. O correto seria:

```
String sql = "SELECT nameClient, userClient, descriptionClient, passwordClient, birtDate FROM Client WHERE userClient LIKE '?%';"
```

Obs: A assinatura do seu método está faltando o tipo do parâmetro userClient

```
public void returInfoClient(TipoDoObjeto userClient) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Na linha 12 você passa a String que será o termo de busca concatenada com o wildcard % do like

```
public void returInfoClient(userClient) {

    Connection mConn = (new ConnectionFactory()).getConnection();

    String sql = "SELECT nameClient, userClient, descriptionClient, passwordClient, birtDate  FROM Client  WHERE userClient LIKE ?";

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = mConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1,  userClient + "%"); 
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
        System.out.println("retornando informações author");
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Se você colocar o `userClient` diretamente na String sql, conforme o R.Santos sugeriu, pode abrir uma brecha para SQL Injection. Você pode ver mais sobre SQL Injection [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).